# Firestore Data retrival asynchronus problem showing "TypeError: Cannot read property '' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Suppose I have some data in firestore. When I call the "Calculation" Function then for each matched element "alld" array is pushed with new objects.
After push(), I get, console.log(alld); It is ok.
But when I call getBl() function, and console.log(alld.n); then it shows all the data, and also showing Error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'n' of undefined at b.$scope.getBl". I could not understand the reason. I know get() is an asynchronous function. I also applied $scope.$applyAsync();. Is this the reason, or there exist some other reason, I don't know.
What could be the solution?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['firebase', 'ngRoute', 'angular.filter']);

app.controller('mCntlr', function ($scope, $firebaseArray) {
  var alld=$scope.alld=[{'n':j,'d':h,'c':l}];
  
  
 $scope.getBl=function (b){
let i=0;
   for(i=0;i<alld.length;i++)
   console.log("check  = "+$scope.alld[i].n); //Consol.log is printing data but it also showing "TypeError: Cannot read property 'n' of undefined"
   };
   
   
   $scope.Calculation = function (e) { firebase.firestore().collection("DataCollection").get()
  .then(function (snapshot) {

    snapshot.docs.forEach(element =>{
       fld =element.data();
       fld.dC.forEach(function(item){ alld.push({'n':item.A,'d':dr,'c':c});
  $scope.$applyAsync();});

     });
         console.log(alld); //it is ok
         $scope.getBl(); 
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: for(i=0;i<alld.length;i++)
   console.log("check  = "+$scope.alld[i].n); 
  Before this for loop, If I write, console.log(alld.length); then it is also showing the length ! Its really confusing !

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
 console.log("check  = "+alld[i].n);
```

As the values of those objects (`n,d,c`) were undefined you were getting this error.
Or instead of using `let i=0;` try using `var i=0;`
and instead of using `var alld=$scope.alld=[{'n':j,'d':h,'c':l}];` try using `$scope.alld=[{'n':j,'d':h,'c':l}];`
then you must have to write `console.log($scope.alld);`

Comment: No. Here main problem is:
console.log("check  = "+$scope.alld[i].n); //Consol.log is printing data but it also showing "TypeError: Cannot read property 'n' of undefined"
How console.log can show data of and typeerror at the same time